# SSH console losing original keyboard layout after killing a .Net Core console app

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, keyboard, yocto

I am currently developing a C# embedded project on a Yocto/Arm32 platform.  It was working just fine with Dotnet Core v3.1, but I just got one annoying problem moving to DotNetCore v6:  When running the software with console output and then killing the process with Control-C, the keyboard layout ended changed!

My questions are:

- How can prevent this from happening, either by changing some DotNet software properties or by adding some command lines to my start script?
- What is so special about DotNetv6 (or v5) that create this change of behavior?

Technical details:

- In the runtimeconfig.json file, we already have "System.Globalization.Invariant": true
- In a custom dotnet.sh file, we also have "export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1"
- The service scripts use the SysV format.
- The service scripts run as "root".
- Using the defaut "root" user configuration (if any).
- We use a PuTTY SSH console with its default settings.
- Using bash command line.
- Using C# v8
- The C# Trace setup code:
  Trace.AutoFlush = true;
  Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
- The startup command line (from my bash script):
  /opt/dotnet-runtime-6.0.13-linux-arm/dotnet  /opt/mystuff/myapp.dll
- I observed no problem if the console output is sent to /dev/null
- Downgrading to a lower C# version has no impact.  The only delta is the DotNet upgrade.
- Changing the App "Assembly neutral language" from "en-US" to "none" did not help.
- I found no cue on how getting the current keybord layout on this stripped Yocto OS (provided by a third-party). The (desperate) plan was to manually restore it after the app kill.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you login to remote device via ssh, start your .net app, kill it with ctrl+c and then your keyboard layout changes?

Comment: @Evk: Exactly.  Also, I log as "admin", then log as "root" (e.g. "su - root"), start and kill the app, and then the keybord layout change (may be the layout change at the app start, but there is no way to tell).  Also, logging out from "root" (e.g. fallback to "admin") and login back again as root does not restore the original layout.  I have to start a new SSH session to get the original layout.  Frankly, I do not see the link with migrating to DotNetv6!

Comment: I'd also be very curious to know how this can be related to.net 6 migration.

Comment: @Evk:  Testing with the Rider default "Hello World!" console application:   1) DotNet v3.1 + SSH PuTTY --> OK;

2) DotNet v6.0 + SSH PuTTY --> BAD;

3) DotNet v6.0 + SSH MobaXterm--> OK;

===> Conclusion: The DotNet v6.0 introduce a new  behavior that PuTTY cannot handle by default, but other SSH tool can.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to change the keyboard settings in PuTTY:

1. Click the PuTTY icon in the upper-left corner of the window.
2. From the drop-down menu, click "Change Settings".
3. Go to the "Terminal" item, and then the "Features" sub-item.
4. Under "Enabling and disabling advanced terminal features", check
   "Disable application keypad mode".
5. Click "Apply".